# How do you know which XML parameters a Spring configuration tag has?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

I was just reading [an article](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-security-hash-salt-passwords-3.html) that showed the following Spring Security XML configuration:

```
<authentication-provider>  
  <password-encoder hash="sha" />  
  <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />  
</authentication-provider>
```

I wondered if password-encoder could take some combination of parameters that would make it use SHA-256.  I easily found the Java constructor for the [ShaPasswordEncoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html), but how can I tell whether the password-encoder tag takes the argument for the Java object?

In general, how can one tell what the tags and parameters for Spring configuration are?

For example, how do I know which that ShaPasswordEncoder goes with "password-encoder" (if indeed it does)?

Comment: The "spring" tag is inappropriate, that refers to the Spring Framework, not Spring Security.

Comment: In both the question title and the embedded question ("In general, how can one tell what the tags and parameters for Spring configuration are?"), I want to know about Spring as a whole.  I used Spring security as an example.

Comment: @skaffman - "In general, how can one tell what the tags and parameters for Spring configuration are?" is a general Spring question so the "spring" tag makes sense. And I would suggest "spring-framework" is for the Spring Framework, and "spring" is for the Spring product suite in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look at the [XML Schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd). For example:

```
<xs:attribute name="hash">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      Defines the hashing algorithm used on user passwords. We recommend
      strongly against using MD4, as it is a very weak hashing algorithm.
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:enumeration value="plaintext"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="sha"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="sha-256"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="md5"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="md4"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="{sha}"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="{ssha}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

So, you should do this:

```
<authentication-provider>  
  <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />  
  <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />  
</authentication-provider>
```

Comment: Great!  In general, the schema is given in xsi:schemaLocation in the config file, so for the bean config I am using http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd.

Comment: But what classes do these enumerated values map to? I don't see where that is defined.